# Accessing super class methods in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model,
a User

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, Base):
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, null=False, unique=True, max_length=255)
```

A base class

```
class Room(Base):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(default=RoomStatus.ACTIVE, max_length=256, null=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    last_activity = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

And two children

```
class LeagueRoom(Room):
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class ClubRoom(Room):
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

I want to access the `leagueroom_set` for the user. I'm not sure how to do this. The user currently has a property `room_set`, but I wish to access the specific room_set. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You are using [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) here. Did you mean for `Room` to be a table in the database, or did you only want it to be a base class to define the shared fields for the league and club models?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't have any real use of the Room, but I can't make it abstract because I need the room id to globally sort all forms of room.

Answer (score 2):

You could start from the other end:

```
league_rooms = LeagueRoom.objects.filter(members=my_user)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you want Room to be an abstract base class. Then what you are trying to do will work. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

   ```
   class Room(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
       # other fields
       …

       class Meta:
           abstract = True
   ```
2. If Room can't be an abstract class, then you'll have to move your members field from Room into each of the subclasses to use the built-in relationships.

   ```
   class LeagueRoom(Room):
       league = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
       location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
       members = models.ManyToManyField(User)

   # same with ClubRoom
   ```
3. Third option I can think of is to set a type attribute on each of your subclasses so that you can filter room_set to the type of room you want.

   ```
   class LeagueRoom(Room):
      …
      type = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='league')
      …
   ```

   Then somewhere else:

   ```
   room_set.filter(type='league')
   ```